# Making divs act like proper links

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink

I'm using a JavaScript (jQuery) calendar where some calendar events act as links. The calendar events are divs that have onclick triggers that point the browser to the correct page.

The problem is that since the calendar event's aren't `<a href="..">` links the user can't ctrl+click to open the link to a new tab or shift+click to open to a new window. I'm looking for a way to get this functionality to the calendar and it seems like my options are:

1. Detect whether the user has shift pressed and open to a new window or ctrl pressed and open to a new tab - I'd rather not do this because opening to a new tab will probably have to be coded separately for each browser (?) and it might override user's preferences.
2. Remove the onclick triggers and wrap the div content inside `<a></a>` that fills the entire enclosing div.
3. Hack the calendar library to use `<a>` tags instead of divs for clickable calendar events.

Is there by any chance any other method to tell the browser to consider divs as regular links? Are there any foreseeable side effects to methods #2 or #3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say your easiest/most complete solution would be to use anchors just as they are (e.g. no script required), just use CSS to do the work here, with `display: block` or `display: inline-block` and *style* them like `<div>` elements.

This way, all the native clicking behavior can be handled by the browser and the user's preferences as well as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>, etc clicking is whatever the user is *expecting* it to do.

Answer (score 0):

Find a calendar that uses proper markup, or fork the plugin and go for #3.  The down side to the later is that since you're forking, you cut yourself off from upgrades